# Moving (shifting) two registers in Assembler

Tags: assembly, shift, 8051

I have 8 LEDs and 2 buttons, initially the first and the last LED are lit, if i press the first button, the first led shifts right, if i press the second button the last led shifts left. If the two lights "meet", by shifting upon each other, they switch off.

I did not know how to update the leds on a single row after pressing the buttons, so I made 2 rows, P1 and P2, for each button. The first row seems to shift properly, but the second is really messed up. What am I doing wrong?

Below is my code:

```
$TITLE(5)
$MOD51
ORG 100H
START: 
    ; 8 leds, P1.0-P1.7
    ; 2 buttons, P0.1 P0.2
    MOV P1, #00h
    MOV P2, #00h

    ; left LED positions
    MOV 30H, #00000001b ; initial position
    MOV 31H, #00000010b  
    MOV 32H, #00000100b  
    MOV 33H, #00001000b  
    MOV 34H, #00010000b             
    MOV 35H, #00100000b  
    MOV 36H, #01000000b  
    MOV 37H, #10000000b 

    MOV 38H, #00000000b ; leds meet

    ; right led positions
    MOV 39H, #10000000b ; initial position
    MOV 40H, #01000000b  
    MOV 41H, #00100000b  
    MOV 42H, #00010000b  
    MOV 43H, #00001000b             
    MOV 44H, #00000100b  
    MOV 45H, #00000010b  
    MOV 46H, #00000001b  

    MOV R1, #0
    MOV R2, #0

 LOOP:  
    JNB P0.1, INCREMENT_L ; left button pressed, led shifts right
    JNB P0.2, INCREMENT_R ; right button pressed, led shifts left

    CALL DISP_L ; display left led
    CALL DISP_R ; display right led

    JMP LOOP

INCREMENT_L:
    SETB P0.1
    CJNE R1, #7, INC_L
    MOV R1, #0
    JMP LOOP

INCREMENT_R:
    SETB P0.2
    CJNE R2, #7, INC_R
    MOV R2, #0
    JMP LOOP

INC_L:
    MOV A, R2
    ADD A, #39H
    MOV B, A
    MOV A, R1
    ADD A, #30H
    CJNE A, B, INCL
    JMP RESET
    JMP LOOP

INC_R:
    MOV A, R1
    ADD A, #30H
    MOV B, A
    MOV A, R2
    ADD A, #39H
    CJNE A, B, INCR
    JMP RESET
    JMP LOOP

INCL:
    INC R1
    JMP LOOP

INCR:
    INC R2
    JMP LOOP

DISP_L:
    MOV A, R1
    ADD A, #30H
    MOV R0, A
    MOV P1, @R0
    RET

DISP_R: 
    MOV A, R2
    ADD A, #39H
    MOV R0, A
    MOV P2, @R0
    RET

RESET:
    MOV R1, #0
    MOV R2, #0
    JMP LOOP

END
```

Comment: Defined "messed up". What is it doing? Also, have you tried commenting out a few lines of code to see how it reacts?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context if you expect a useful answer.  What kind of cpu and how are the leds/buttons hooked up at the very least.

Comment: "messed up" as in, when testing with the sim535 program, the first line of leds shifts "cleanly", from 10000000 (where 0 signifies an unlit led and 1 a lit led), to 00000001 (shifting 1 led at a time), while the second row, at the first push of the button displays 11111100 instead of 00000010, and at the second push it displays 01111010 instead of 00000100, and then other weird values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds an awful lot like a signed/unsigned issue.  Is your add unsigned, or does it assume the high bit is a sign bit and do the 2s compliment stuff for you.  Any carry bits left over could also affect things if not careful as well.  Do you have a straight shift instruction instead of using add?

Looked online real quick and see you do have a SHL/SHR instruction you could use to move your bits around.  Then, you just xor against your location to turn the bit off if they match.

Comment: oh so i'd have just 2 registers, one containing 00000001 and the other 10000000 as initial values and use SHR / SHL to move the bits. Just one more question: how could i "merge" the bits from these 2 registers? like for example if i have 00001000 and 1000000 and i'd like to "merge" them into 10001000

Comment: i'm using 8x51 architecture so i have RRC and RLC instead of SHR / SHL

Comment: Use xor.  If the bits are the same, it will return a 0.  Something like dhl r0, xor against r1 and place in r2.  Display r2.  Same the other way, shr r1, xor against r0, place and display in r2.  That should give you the result you want.  BTW, using RRC and RLC (assuming it means Rotate Left thru Carry and Rotate Right Thru Carry) means you can shift the set bit all the way through the lights in either direction, into carry, then back out the otherside by just repeatedly calling the rotate.  Kinda neat.